# How do you retain the current IndexPath.row in a Table View when going from one View Controller to another such as Instagram or Facebook in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, viewcontroller, indexpath

I am trying to retain the current IndexPath.row of a cell in a Table View when passing from one View Controller to another such as Instagram or Facebook. Every time I move from one View Controller to another, I have to call reloadData() for the Table View to load it back. But when I do this, I lose the current position before going to a new View Controller.

I can get it to work on didSelect by passing the current IndexPath.row between Controllers, but if the user is just scrolling, it becomes buggy trying to do that.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and depends strongly on the context. Please add the relevant code and what you are going to do with the index path.

Comment: It’s really not that ambiguous. When you go from one view controller to another, then back, my tableview cells start at index path 0. I am using dynamic cells. I am just trying to retain the current index path. If a user is at the middle of a tableview, say the index path is 7, but when you go from one view controller with a new table view, then back to the original tableview, it now sets the index path back to 0. Instagram and Facebook retains the user’s current index path regardless of how many screens they navigate through. This is what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `reloadData` keeps the `contentOffset`. However, it could be updated if you do have inaccurate `estimatedRowHeight` values.

Calling `reloadData` on the `tableView` does not change the content offset. However, if you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` which was introduced in iOS 13, you could have an issue.

While using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, one needs to write the delegate method `tableView: estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` along with `tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:` which also returns the same.

For me, I had issues in iOS 13 while using this. It was because the method `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` method was returning inaccurate values even though I was using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. It was problem with iOS 13 as there was no issue with iOS 13 devices.

I solved this problem by using a `dictionary` to store the value of the cell's height and returning it. This is what I did.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSNumber *key = @(indexPath.row);
    NSNumber *height = @(cell.frame.size.height);

    [self.cellHeightsDictionary setObject:height forKey:key];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSNumber *key = @(indexPath.row);
    NSNumber *height = [self.cellHeightsDictionary objectForKey:key];

    if (height)
    {
        return height.doubleValue;
    }

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Maybe that is my issue. I have dynamic tableview cells with estimated heights that I create based on whether there is an image or not. I will try to convert your code to swift and see if that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as u said u can save the position and in viewDidLoad of the new viewController scroll to that index:

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: <IndexPath>, at: <UITableView.ScrollPosition>, animated: <Bool>)
```

set animated to false and scrollPosition to whatever fits u, example .top, and the indexPath u just pass between view controllers. try to alternate where to use this function in viewDidLoad or viewWillApear.